# Angular JS : ng-style is not working while passing data to directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using ng-style for populating width of an element.

**Code**:

```
<div ng-style="{'width':'{{cols}}'+'px'}" id="autocompleteSuggestions" class="autocompleteSuggestionsDropdown" ng-show="autoSuggestion && searchText.length>2">
```

**developer option preview**

```
<div ng-style="{'width':'445'+'px'}" id="autocompleteSuggestions" class="autocompleteSuggestionsDropdown" ng-show="autoSuggestion &amp;&amp; searchText.length>2">
```

The issue is my cols valiable is getting printed on the html (while looking from the developer options) but style is not getting applied on it.

Can someone help me out in this ?

Comment: I infact found the way : by using it like this <div ng-style="{width: cols+'px'}" id="autocompleteSuggestions" class="autocompleteSuggestionsDropdown" ng-show="autoSuggestion && searchText.length>2">

Comment: ng-style itself is an interpolation right so no need of {{}} :)

Comment: Yes vinod I just answered that . So, dumb of me :(

Answer (score 0):

I have found the way tosolve this problem, I don't have to use the expression tag as ng-style is a angular directive and digest cycle will anyway parse it. Although wirting an expression was still resolving the variable but it was giving error to the ng-style syntax. So, I have used the variable without using expression and it worked.

```
<div ng-style="{width: cols+'px'}" id="autocompleteSuggestions" class="autocompleteSuggestionsDropdown" ng-show="autoSuggestion && searchText.length>2">
```